# Not able to retrieve items from the database

Tags: android, mysql

I am able to create and add items to the database but retrieval from the database is not happening 
Its showing as no columns found.. A part of the code is as shown ! please help

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_QUES + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_A + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_B + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_C + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_D + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );
```

//adding entry

```
    public long createEntry(String ques, String a, String b, String c, String d) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_QUES, ques);
    cv.put(KEY_A, a);
    cv.put(KEY_B, b);
    cv.put(KEY_C, c);
    cv.put(KEY_D, d);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

//Retriving an entry

```
public String getName(long l) throws SQLException{
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_QUES, KEY_A, KEY_B, KEY_C,KEY_D};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l,     null,  null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        friends.question = c.getString(1);
        friends.a = c.getString(2);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: where you getting problem for retriving an entry time is c object is null or you getting error at c.getString() time

Comment: java.lang - It is saying that the coulmn is not found..i put try catch and it works fine until the retrival

Comment: It looks like your table didn't get created - are you sure that the code db.execSQL is actually being called? Put a breakpoint on it to check.

Comment: Yea..the table is getting created..and i am to insert., why did you think that the table is not created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the edited code for retrieve purpose.

```
public String getName(long l) throws SQLException{
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_QUES, KEY_A, KEY_B, KEY_C,KEY_D};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=?",     new String[] {Long.toString(l)},  null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        friends.question = c.getString(1);
        friends.a = c.getString(2);

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: set KEY_ROWID as string type.

Comment: No I have to use it as a integer for my app..and I tried that already ..it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

it think you initialize  column name

```
Cursor cur=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null,null, null,  null, null, null);
```

to see what table contain exactly.If it contain diffrent column name then use them,
May be you have done initialize

```
like KEY_A="key_a" like this then use
```

that orignal value.
**make sure to use getReadbleDatabase while reading and getWritableDatabase() while inserting**